# How to stop wocommerce checkout redirection

Tags: wordpress

My wocommerce cart and checkout page redirects to another website whenever i click on it instead of the payment gateway. I have changed the theme severally still it persist. I use flatsome theme

How do i stop this?

Comment: Can you share your code with us? It's difficult to answer your question if we can't not see the source of the problem.

Comment: Which part of the code, i used wordpress themes and plugin